# Excel: take ID from one list to another list

Tags: excel, list, uniqueidentifier

I want to combine two lists with the ID from one of them but haven't found a solution for this. These are my two lists:

List 1:

```
NAME  | CAR
john  | audi
karen | opel
```

List 2:

```
CAR  |  ID
audi |  1
opel |  2
```

what I want is the ID to get from list 2 to list 1, so that my list 1 will look like:

```
NAME |  CAR  | ID
john |  audi | 1
```

and so on…

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use procv function

Exemple

=VLOOKUP(CAR;LIST2;2;0)

where CAR is cell with name of car and LIST2 is range of cell with list 2.

Comment: thank you - vlookup was exactly what is was looking for.the code: `=vlookup(a2;'dataSheet'!$A$2:$C$40;4;FALSE)`

Comment: You can improve this function to display on error "not found" do it this way: IFERROR(vlookup(a2;'dataSheet'!$A$2:$C$40;4;FALSE);"Not Found")